# CPAN install module failed: don't know what it is

Tags: perl, cpan, catalyst

I am installing this module in Ubuntu:

http://metacpan.org/pod/CatalystX::DynamicComponent::ModelsFromConfig

with bash command:

```
sudo cpan CatalystX::DynamicComponent::ModelsFromConfig
```

However I always get this message:

```
Warning: Cannot install CatalystX::DynamicComponent::ModelsFromConfig, don't know what it is.
```

Is this means this module is not a standard module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no stable, indexed release of that module, only a developer preview release. With a recent version of cpanminus you could do

```
cpanm --dev CatalystX::DynamicComponent::ModelsFromConfig
```

with regular CPAN.pm you should be able to do

```
cpan BOBTFISH/CatalystX-DynamicComponent-0.000000_01.tar.gz
```

That or come onto irc.perl.org #catalyst and talk to t0m about the module and whether it makes sense for you to be using it — it seems to be abandoned since 2009. I think the sensible replacement is [CatalystX::ComponentsFromConfig](http://p3rl.org/CatalystX%3a%3aComponentsFromConfig).